# Generic Key object same as value of other key

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to make type with same key of object as value of other key

I want to receive `_Option` type from data which has key same as a value of value key:

```
data = {
  asd: {
    value: "asd",
    label: "Asd",
    active: false,
  },
  qwe: {
    value: "qwe",
    label: "Qwe",
    active: true,
  },
};



const options = getOptionsFromDetails(data)
```

I want to force usage of this fn that key must be same as value of value key, below example with an warning: `An index signature parameter type cannot be a literal type or generic type. Consider using a mapped object type instead.` I tried to do it also using mapped object but get `unknown` on values :(

```
type _Option<TValue extends string> = {
  value: TValue;
  label: string;
};

export const getOptionsFromDetails = <TKey extends string>(
  details: {
    [key: TKey]: {
      value: TKey;
      label: string;
      active: boolean;
    };
  }, 
): _Option<TKey>[] =>
```

Comment: "key must be same as value of value key" <-- could you rewrite this so my brain doesn't explode?  (edit: I understand what you mean but it's a *very* confusing way of saying it)

Comment: @jcalz - `data.asd` matches `data.asd.value`'s value `"asd"`. Took me a second too.

Comment: I still don't get it

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NBd5nW) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer (but please [edit] the question to describe things clearly. If you want me to do it, I will).  If not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The error message is correct about what to do: Use a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#handbook-content) for the type of `details`. For me, it's clearest to do that separately with a type alias:

```
type Details<TKey extends string> = {
    [Key in TKey]: {
        value: Key;
        label: string;
        active: boolean;
    };
};

export const getOptionsFromDetails = <TKey extends string>(
    details: Details<TKey>
): _Option<TKey>[] => {
    // ...
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=50&ssc=1&pln=62&pc=1#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)

Then this using your example data works:

```
const a = getOptionsFromDetails({
    asd: {
        value: "asd",
        label: "Asd",
        active: false,
    },
    qwe: {
        value: "qwe",
        label: "Qwe",
        active: true,
    },
});
```

...but this fails as expected because `xxx` doesn't match `value: "asd"`:

```
const b = getOptionsFromDetails({
    xxx: {
        value: "asd",
        label: "Asd",
        active: false,
    },
    qwe: {
        value: "qwe",
        label: "Qwe",
        active: true,
    },
});
```

This also fails as desired (just another check to make sure the type didn't allow swapping the keys):

```
const c = getOptionsFromDetails({
    qwe: {
        value: "asd",
        label: "Asd",
        active: false,
    },
    asd: {
        value: "qwe",
        label: "Qwe",
        active: true,
    },
});
```